# Ubuntu 12.04 installed on hard disk using USB pendrive does not boot from hard disk

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, hard-drive, usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using USB pendirve but it only boots if that USB is connected. It does not boot from the hard disk. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Live USB, ubuntu installer installs the grub onto the USB instead of the hard disk. Boot with your Live USB and (considering sda is your primary HDD partition)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall it  , and at the Grub installation prompt , install Grub on your Hard drive , Preferably on sda . Make sure you are installing Ubuntu on your Hard drive and not in your USB .