# Boot problem Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, power-management

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 but the system crashed and now will not boot from the hard drive, I can only start from the CD ROM. I already formatted and reinstalled Ubuntu, but when I start a message appears from the disk power management (often outside) then the screen goes black and nothing happens.

Comment: maybe you can add more details... follow some of this directions http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into and these one too http://askubuntu.com/questions/47623/list-the-hardware-info-and-status-in-my-computer

Answer (score 0):

Is this computer of yours dual-booting with another operating system, like Windows 7? If so, you can restore your Windows 7 partition by reading a link in Microsoft Answers. Let me know if this is the case and I'll paste the link for you to follow.

Comment: Brian, your answer in the current state doesn't really have any useful component. Can you at the very least add the link to the MS answers, so someone else in the future could benefit from it as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert. Look at this question and see if you did anything similar here and then ask your question again as was specified with more info:

[Ubuntu 12.04 installed on hard disk using USB pendrive does not boot from hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/q/137204/65839)

Comment: Is it over heating? Is it the battery?